# I need a formula to return cells from a range that have a capital letter at the start and numbers at the end

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of usernames that are made up of letters and numbers. I need to find a way of listing all the usernames that have a capital letter at the beginning and end with a number. Is it possible to do this with either a formula or with code?

The usernames could be in a list of up to 1000 and can range in length from 5 characters up to 12.

Answer (score 2):

The 'CODE' function will return a numeric value for the first character given, the codes for capitals letters are between 65 and 90, and the codes for numbers are between 48 and 57.

Combining those with the RIGHT function to get the last character, the function

```
AND(CODE(A1)>=65,CODE(A1)<=90,CODE(RIGHT(A1))>=48,CODE(RIGHT(A1))<=57)
```

will return true if it fits your criteria (using A1 as the cell containing the username). You should be able to filter on that.

Minor caveat, but this only includes capitals in the English alphabet. If you might have foreign capitals, this is a LOT more challenging.

Comment: Nice, maybe shorter a bit to: `=AND(CODE(A1)>=65,CODE(A1)<=90,ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A1)*1))`

Comment: Unfortunately not- RIGHT(A1) will be the text value "1", not an actual number.

Comment: hence the *1 =)

Comment: Oh, never noticed that! Hacky, but effective.